# Java weird NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, oop, static, jvm

I keep getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` whenever I try to run this block of code

```
ClassTable.getInstance();
```

Here is the code for ClassTable

```
public class ClassTable
{
    private static ClassTable classTable = new ClassTable();
    private Map<String,Object> pricingTable;
    private Date expiry;


    private ClassTable()
    {
        this.expiry = this.getExpiry();
        this.pricingTable = buildPricingTables();
    }

    private Date getExpiry()
    {
        return DateUtils.INSTANCE.getCutOff();
    }

    public static ClassTable getInstance()
    {
      return classTable;
    }
}
```

I tried stepping into the method `getInstance()`; however, it throws the error instantly. Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class helper.ClassTable
    at models.SinglePaymentLoan.getPricingTable(SinglePaymentLoan.java:742)
    at unit.SinglePaymentLoanTest.testPricingTable(SinglePaymentLoanTest.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$2$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:114)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:112)
    at controllers.TestRunner$1.doJobWithResult(TestRunner.java:71)
    at controllers.TestRunner$1.doJobWithResult(TestRunner.java:1)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: It means that you are missing a jar or a class in your build path. This could happen because you did not put it there or did not build the project.

Comment: Where's `DateUtils` that you're trying to access coming from?

Comment: From what I can see most probably DateUtils is the problem since this is required by the ClassTable constructor.  Maybe a compilation problem?

Answer (score 2):

Note that it states that it cannot initialize the class. That indicates a problem with static initialization of the class.

You have one static variable `classTable` that attempts to create a new ClassTable instance.

```
private static ClassTable classTable = new ClassTable();
private Map<String,Object> pricingTable;
private Date expiry;

private ClassTable()
{
    this.expiry = this.getExpiry();
    this.pricingTable = buildPricingTables();
}
```

So now any error in creating a ClassTable instance will lead to a class initialization failure. You do 2 things in the constructor, each of which could fail.

You call `getExpiry`, which we see turns and calls `DateUtils.INSTANCE.getCutOff()`. You have not provided this code, so it is unclear what this does.

Finally, you call `buildPricingTables()`. Again, code has not been provided for this method.

So your 2 mostly likely culprits are `DateUtils.INSTANCE.getCutOff()` and `buildPricingTables()`.